# asp.net get item from list in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this object like so `[ { job: "ABC-123", task: "XYZ" },  { job: "ABC-333", task: "LAX" }];`

That object is from an ajax call to here:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendorItem(List<VendorUpdateClass> edittedItems)
        {
            ConnectionClass jobs = new ConnectionClass();
            return jobs.updateVendors(edittedItems);
        }
```

which calls this class:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(List<VendorUpdateClass> items)
        {
            VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();

            foreach (object objectItems in items)
            {
                VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = objectItems.job;
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = objectItems.job;
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = objectItems.task;

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            }


            return VendorUpdateCell;
        }
```

my issue is with my loop. I am trying to assign the `job` and `task` from the object to `vendorUpdatedItem` Here is the errors I am getting:

`'object' does not contain a definition for 'job' and no extension method 'job' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
foreach (object objectItems in items)
```

you are specifically treating each item in the list as an [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx). You know the data type so you can do it with the actual data type:

```
foreach (VendorUpdateClass objectItems in items)
```

or you could just let the compiler do it for you because the compiler knows too:

```
foreach (var objectItems in items)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
foreach (object objectItems in items)
```

to

```
foreach (var objectItems in items)
```

The compiler is able to derive the correct class (`VendorUpdateClass`) if you use `var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(List<VendorUpdateClass> items)
    {
        VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();

        foreach (VendorUpdateClass objectItems in items)
        {
            VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();
            vendorUpdatedItem.job = objectItems.job;
            vendorUpdatedItem.task = objectItems.job;
            vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = objectItems.task;

            VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
        }


        return VendorUpdateCell;
    }
```

Change the foreach to VendorUpdateClass instead of object since you are looping over a collection of VendorUpdateClass.